# DevExpress SkinEditor Resources

Tags: devexpress

Looking to find a better knowledge base on using DevExpress's SkinEditor. I was hoping to see if there were any resources out there other than DevExpress's lack luster Documentation & Support. I am coming from more of a Graphic & Web Design background not so much UX/UI. The features that are there are limited by my knowledge of what each piece is used for (I.E. Button, TabHeader). Its the element I am not sure of or do not use, that has me stumped. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is much better then documentation of devExpress. Everything is much clear there. well you can look at the deveExpress Blog and Documentation that give you step by step approach.

Check these links:
[About DevExpress skinning and custom skins](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/01/15/About-DevExpress-skinning-and-custom-skins.aspx)
[Creating New Skins](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#SkinEditor/CustomDocument2547)
[Creating Custom Skins - DevExpress Blog](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/the_final_cut/archive/2008/09/16/creating-custom-skins.aspx)

Check the search result for [Custom Skin here](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=custom%20skin&p=T0%7CP0%7C0&d=576), which should be fare enough to assist you..

Comment: Thanks for the info, I watched Erica (http://bit.ly/aH2bGF) from DevExpress (vintage 2008) last week. Her video while informative on the use of Photoshop's Action recorder was helpful, I need more of a navigation chart to navigate the SkinEditor's asset list. More importantly do I remake every single one of the assets? Or can I create a subset of what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that DX support guys http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question will refer you to the best way ;)